# How flattening a nested list using `sum(iterable,[])` works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm using python 3.6. I came across the below way to flatten the nested list using `sum`:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

sum(a,[])
```

which returns:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

---

What exactly is going on here? Sum takes an iterable, in this case a list, and a start value. I don't understand what python reads to flatten the list.

Comment: *Don't do that*, and also where the heck did the 6 go?

Comment: Accidentally missed it. Edit has been made.

Comment: **Better:**  `[x for sublist in a for x in sublist]`.  **Why better:**  duck-types for tuples.  Doesn't create a bunch of useless intermediate lists which just get deleted quickly after.

Comment: Why is that better? Usually I used in-list loop, but this seems much better...

Comment: Not *quite* a dup, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/1040092) answer discussed this.

Comment: @wim or better still `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))`.

Comment: So in order to create a six item list this creates an empty list, then a brand new two item list, then a brand new four item list, then finally a six item list. All previous lists are thrown away. At each step all the references are copied. The performance is horrible. You might not notice it with list this small, but indescriminate use of algorithms like this kill performance even if you're using the fastest of languages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just a result of how Python interprets addition of lists. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

> `sum(iterable[, start])`
>
> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total.

Since `sum` starts by adding the first element of the iterable to the `start` argument, you have:

```
[] + [1, 2] = [1, 2]
```

Then it continues adding items from the iterable:

```
[1, 2] + [3, 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] + [5, 6] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 8):

`sum([a, b, c], d)` produces `d + a + b + c`.

In your example, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are `[1, 2]`, `[3, 4]`, `[5, 6]`, and `[]`.

`sum([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [])` produces `[] + [1, 2] + [3, 4] + [5, 6]`, which is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` because `+` is concatenation for lists.

This is *absurdly inefficient*, because every `+` operation involved requires copying all the data from each of its arguments:

```
In [7]: x = [[i] for i in range(30000)]

In [8]: %timeit sum(x, [])
1 loop, best of 3: 2.06 s per loop

In [9]: %timeit [elem for sublist in x for elem in sublist]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

`sum(x, [])` takes quadratic time, whereas a more efficient implementation takes linear time. Never do `sum(x, [])`.

Comment: Joel Spolsky calls things like `sum(x, [])` [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). ;)

Answer (score 6):

As the [`sum(iterable[, start])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) document says:

> **Sums `start` and the items of an `iterable` from left to right and returns the total**. `start` defaults to 0. The `iterable`’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

So, in the example you shared:

```
sum(a,[])
```

Here, `iterable` is `a` *(which is `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`)* and `start` is `[]`. Hence, the resultant is equivalent to:

```
[] + [1, 2] + [3, 4] + [5, 6]

# i.e. you flatten list --> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `start` argument gives the function the starting point. It's what is being added to. So `sum([1,2,3])` returns `6` and `sum([1,2,3],5)` returns `11`. In your case, because you're passing in an 2-d list and an empty list, the function is going to add everything in the first argument to the second argument. Essentially, you're doing this:

```
[]+[1,2]+[3,4]+[5,6]
```

It's a bit of a quirk of python's operator overloading.