# Take elements from multiple lists

Tags: python, list

Given multiple lists like the ones shown:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
c = [9, 0, 1]
d = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
...
```

I want to be able to combine them to take as many elements from the first list as I can before starting to take elements from the second list, so the result would be:

```
result = [1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7]
```

Is there a particularly nice way to write this? I can't think of a really simple one without a `for` loop. Maybe a list comprehension with a clever `zip`.

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry

Comment: So `c` has to be left out completely?

Comment: Do they have to be all separate lists? Or can the input be a list of lists?

Comment: You can let them be a list of lists, either works for me :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple slicing and concatenation:

```
a + b[len(a):]
```

Or with more lists:

```
res = []
for lst in (a, b, c, d):
    res += lst[len(res):]
# [1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Oh okay. Yes, I didn't include this in my question. But I wanted a solution that works with as many lists as you give it. But this is definitely correct for what I asked (doh!) I better make an edit.

Comment: Yep, this is genius! Thank you for that :D I had to stop for a while to realise what it was doing

Answer (score 2):

With `itertools.zip_longest()` for Python 3, works on any number of input lists:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [next(x for x in t if x is not None) for t in zip_longest(a,b,c,d)]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7]
```

The default fill value is `None` so take the first none `None` element in each tuple created with the `zip_longest` call (you can change the defaults and criteria if `None` is a valid data value)

Comment: I like the approach, but the comprehensive generation of all tuples `t` makes this rather unperformant as all elements of all lists are touched once.

Comment: @schwobaseggl it might be slower than your solution but hard to be sure without timing on different data sets, your solution (which I also like) also has the `len()` calls and the slower `for` loop etc.

Comment: Sure, needs to be tested and probably depends on the actual data. Algorithmically speaking, however,  mine should be `O(L)` (L being the length of the longest list) as slicing and extending is `O(k)` (k being length of the slice/extension) and `len` being `O(1)`. Yours should be `O(N*L)`. Still, the underlying thought *"Take first existing elemnt at given index"* is nicely reflected.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Agreed!

Comment: A minor variation: `[next(filter(None.__ne__, t)) for t in zip_longest(*src)]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

With `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
print(list(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[len(a):], [a, b, c, d])))
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7]
```

Comment: schwobaseggl's version is more efficient since the loop extends the result list. Whereas using `reduce` like that creates a new list object for each temporary result. This is similar to doing `sum(x, [])`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887692/4014959) for why that's bad.